# Multiple If Query Statements?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I have this code running, "B5 references a name."

(The code is all on one line, but this makes it easier to read)

`=IFERROR(IF(QUERY({'Pokemon (NatDex)'!$A$2:$U;'Pokemon (Evolutions)'!$A$2:$U},"Select * Where Col1=1 and` `Col4 Contains '"&B5&"'"),CHAR(10004)),"x")&""&IFERROR(IF(QUERY({'Pokemon (NatDex)'!$A$2:$U;'Pokemon` `(Evolutions)'!$A$2:$U},"Select * Where Col18=1 and Col20 Contains '"&B5&"'"),CHAR(11088)),"x")`

Right now, if it finds the B5 name listed on NatDex OR Evolutions sheet AND it's corresponding row = 1, it will display character 10004. Great! However the next If function becomes dependant on the first one, but I want it to work independantly.

I didn't use IFS because I want it to return different characters under the different conditions. I'm guessing the `&""&` connecting them makes the 2nd dependant on the first, but how else can you have multiple functions in one cell? If I change it to a comma it causes an error. If I wrap the whole thing in an OR function it returns "OR has no valid input data".

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Isolated each statement and realized what I did wrong. It looked through the whole table with both statements (which I thought was fine, since I selected a specific column to pull from). However, I'm guessing because there are multiple columns with 1 or 0 values on the same row, *that's* what screwed it up.

To fix it, I changed the range so that only one column with numerical values can be seen. Here is what that looks like for future reference:

```
=IFERROR(IF(QUERY({'Pokemon (NatDex)'!$A$2:$D;'Pokemon (Evolutions)'!$A$2:$D},"Select * 
Where Col1=1 and Col4 Contains '"&B5&"'"),CHAR(10004)),"x")&""&IFERROR(IF(QUERY({'Pokemon 
(NatDex)'!$R$2:$U;'Pokemon (Evolutions)'!$R$2:$U},"Select * Where Col1=1 and Col3 Contains 
'"&B5&"'"),CHAR(11088)),"x")
```